# Show all matching grep results in new tab in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, grep, vi, ctags

I am attempting to map a hotkey to do the following in Vim:

1. Match the current c-word currently marked by the cursor
2. Generate a list of all found occurrences in current project
3. Open a new tab showing the results

So, one example I have that uses CTAGS opens the declaration of a variable/function in a new tab like so:

```
map <C-\> :split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

When it hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>, a new tab is opened with the declaration of the variable/function the cursor is on.

The command I am trying to map is shown below:

```
:lvim /\<\(text_i_want_to_find\)\>/gj *.c
:lw
```

When I run this command, a new tab is opened showing a list of all `.c` files containing the text `text_i_want_to_find`. I need to modify this to do two things different from what it does now:

1. Search all files with extensions of `.c`, `.h`, `.cpp`, `.mk`, instead of just `.c`, and also search files named "Makefile"
2. Search for the c-word under the cursor like the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> mapping I have shown above, as opposed to having to manually type in the text `text_i_want_to_find`

Here is the code in my `.vimrc` file for the mapping. I'm not entirely sure if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> can be mapped at all, so there's one more problem for me to solve.

```
map <C-/> :split<CR>:lvim /\<\(.expand("<cword>")\)\>/gj *.c *.h *.cpp *.mk Makefile
```

Does anyone have any tips on fixing this Vim mapping?

---

EDIT:

After reviewing the answers provided to me, here's the final version of my code:

```
command! -nargs=1 SearchAll execute " grep -srnw --binary-files=without-match --exclude={*~,tags} --exclude-dir=.svn  . -e " . expand("<args>") . " " <bar> cwindow
map <C-g> :SearchAll <cword><CR>
```

I mapped it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>. I can also invoke it like so as a colon command:

```
:SearchAll my_text_to_search_for
```

Hope this helps others as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, it does not work: you forgot `:execute`, `:lvimgrep` command on its own does not accept expressions, so you are searching for `expand("<cword>")` that is not followed by a keyword character (`\>`) and preceded by any character that does not follow keyword character (`\<.`). `\(` and `\)` are useless here. Other notes:

1. Don’t use `map`: you need neither this mapping working in visual and operator-pending modes nor ability to use other mappings.
2. Some patterns can be merged: `*.[ch] *.cpp *.mk Makefile` or even `*.{[ch],cpp,mk} Makefile`.
3. `<C-\>` can be mapped, but not `<C-/>` (I hope only currently, but no real work on fixing it is done): `\` is 0x5C and `<C-\>` is 0x5C-0x40=0x1C. But `/` is 0x2F and 0x2F-0x40<0. On my system pressing `<C-/>` in terminal transforms into `<C-_>`, so does `<C-->`.
4. `:split` command does not open a new tab, it opens a new window. Prepend it with `:tab` to do this.
5. `:lvimgrep` is not going to show you the results. It is not either going to jump to the first result unless you remove the `j` flag.
6. You forgot final `<CR>` as well as `:lw<CR>`. I use `:lopen` below, in this context they produce just the same result.
7. You forgot `<C-u>` after first `:` or `<C-\><C-n>` before: it is needed to discard count.
8. You don’t really need `:execute` in either of your mappings because there is `<C-r>=expand("cword")<CR>`, or a default shortcut `<C-r><C-w>`.
9. Don’t write `:exec(str)`: it is confusing because `:execute` is not a function and this syntax encourages others to think it is. Use `:execute str`.

Thus the final mapping is:

```
nnoremap <C-\> :<C-u>tab split \| lvimgrep /\V\<<C-r><C-w>\>/gj *.{[ch],cpp,mk} Makefile \| lopen<CR>
```

. Replace it with

```
nnoremap <C-\> :<C-u>lvimgrep /\V\<<C-r><C-w>\>/gj *.{[ch],cpp,mk} Makefile \| tab lopen<CR>
```

if you don’t want to see the current file in a newly opened tab.

Both mappings assume you have neither `/` nor `\` in `'iskeyword'` option, if you do replace `<C-r><C-w>` with `<C-r>=escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\')<CR>`.

Comment: Thank you. I found a partial answer eventually on the Vim wiki as well: map <F4> :execute " grep -srnw --binary-files=without-match --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-from=exclude.list . -e " . expand("<cword>") . " " <bar> cwindow<CR>

Comment: @Dogbert Vim wiki contains a bunch of bad coded advices, I never use it: knowledge of Vim help is enough. They can be useful, but *every* time I saw a link to vim wiki I saw code that must not be used *as-is* if I followed the link. There is a good advice to break almost any vim tip: exchange `:` and `;` with mappings `noremap : ;` and `noremap ; :`. // These mappings are used by people because omitting shift may be a significant speed up with `;` being still usable.